# Hashing non ascii characters C#

Tags: c#, md5

Here are two hash generators:

1. http://www.md5hashgenerator.com/index.php
2. http://www.miraclesalad.com/webtools/md5.php

Now, my question is:
Why do the hashes differ when trying to hash the char '€' (0x80)?
I assume it happens because '€' is not a normal ASCII character.
Which of the two hashes is 'correct'?

I'm trying to calculate the hash returned by hash generator 1 with C#.
This hashing function doesn't return it.

```
private string GetMD5Hash(string TextToHash)
{
        if ((TextToHash == null) || (TextToHash.Length == 0))
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
        MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] textToHash = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(TextToHash);
        byte[] result = md5.ComputeHash(textToHash);
        return BitConverter.ToString(result).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
}
```

How could I change it so it returns the hash I want?

---

Additional Info:
I made a little AutoIt script:

```
#include  <Crypt.au3>
ConsoleWrite(StringLower(StringMid(_Crypt_HashData(Chr(128), $CALG_MD5),3)) & @CRLF)
```

and it returns the hash I want!
However I need a C# code :)

Comment: so changing "Encoding.Default.GetBytes" to "Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes"?

Comment: I don't think it's wrong as the AutoIt code gets the right hash. So what's it doing differently??

Comment: @Alex: There's no such thing as "the right hash" without specifying the encoding it's using... hashes are applied to binary data, not strings - so we need to know what *binary* data is being hashed.

Comment: With "the right hash" I meant the hash I need :) but thanks for clearing this up!

Comment: Two other notes: it isn't that `€` "isn't a normal ASCII character" - rather: it isn't an ASCII character *at all*. Also, it is not meaningful to say that it is "0x80" - that depends on the encoding. The only useful number (without the encoding) is the unicode codepoint, which is 0x20AC

Comment: Well, I said that because this site http://www.ascii-code.com/ shows € as an extended ASCII character..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It comes down to which encoding you use to turn the `string` into a `byte[]` (hence my suggestion to use try UTF-8, as that is a pretty common choice here; however, any full unicode encoding would work as long as you know which to use) ; for example, based on the string `"abc€"` we can deduce that the first site might be using any of:

```
874: Thai (Windows)
936: Chinese Simplified (GB2312)
1250: Central European (Windows)
1252: Western European (Windows)
1253: Greek (Windows)
1254: Turkish (Windows)
1255: Hebrew (Windows)
1256: Arabic (Windows)
1257: Baltic (Windows)
1258: Vietnamese (Windows)
50227: Chinese Simplified (ISO-2022)
51936: Chinese Simplified (EUC)
52936: Chinese Simplified (HZ)
```

Personally, I'd use UTF-8!

Here's the code I used to find the candidate encodings:

```
    MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
    foreach (var enc in Encoding.GetEncodings())
    {
        byte[] textToHash = enc.GetEncoding().GetBytes("abc€");
        byte[] result = md5.ComputeHash(textToHash);
        var output = BitConverter.ToString(result).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
        if(output == "7a66042043b2cc38ba16a13c596d740e")
        {  // result from http://www.md5hashgenerator.com/index.php
            Console.WriteLine(enc.CodePage + ": " + enc.DisplayName);
        }
    }
```

Further, testing with the string `"dnos ʇǝqɐɥdʃɐ"` shows that the second site is definitely using UTF-8; the first site finds no matches, so I guess it is using a code-page based encoding, and in short **will not work reliably** with the full range of unicode.

Comment: Thank you very much! That helped alot. I'll try it out once I'm home :) I'd love to give you +1, but I can't :(

Comment: +1 on Alex's behalf.  And I confirm that site 2 is UTF 8 and site 1 is apparently Western European...

Comment: @Alex if Garry is correct and it is indeed Western European, then you would use `Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes(...)`

Answer (score 3):

Both of the MD5 pages you've shown describe MD5 as an operation which works on strings. It isn't - it's an operation which works on *byte* sequences. In order to convert from a string to a byte sequence, you need to use an *encoding*.

You've chosen `Encoding.Default` which is almost always a bad choice - I'd generally choose `Encoding.UTF8`. However, importantly, neither of those sites say what *they're* using. However, in real life I would *hope* you'd either have control over both hashing processes (assuming there really are two) or that any hashing code you don't have control over will specify what encoding to use.

Note that there's a simpler way of creating an instance of `MD5` - just use `MD5.Create`. You should also generally put it in a `using` statement as it implements `IDisposable`:

```
private static string GetMD5Hash(string text)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
    {
        return "";
    }
    using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
    {
        byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text));
        return BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
    }
}
```